# Can not convert character to numeric in R

Tags: r

I'm struggling to convert a character vector to numeric in R. I import a dataframe from csv with:

```
a = read.csv('myData.csv', header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

One of my factors, `fac1`, is a vector of numbers but contains some instances of "na" and "nr". Hence, `typeof(a$fac1)` returns `"character"`

I create a new dataframe without "na" and "nr" entries

```
k = a[a$fac1 != "na" & a$fac1 != "nr", ]
```

I then try to convert `fac1` to numeric with:

```
k$fac1_num = as.numeric(k$fac1)
```

The problem is that this doesn't work, as `typeof(k$fac1_num)` now returns `"double"` instead of `"numeric"`

Can anyone suggest a fix / point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you've done everything right, it's just that R's terminology around types is a little...convoluted, sometimes. `typeof` never returns `numeric`. Compare with the results of `class()` (and be sure to read the documentation on both functions!).

Comment: ah, that cleared up a lot of confusion! I think that sub-setting my data was also causing a problem - so using as.numeric without any subsetting (as shown in the answer below) still returned `character` when using `typeof`, but `class` returns `numeric` as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just coercing to numeric:

```
a = read.csv('myData.csv', header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
a$fac1_num = as.numeric(a$fac1)
```

If you need to subset (which is generally not needed and I would advise against doing routinely since there might be value in knowing what the other column value tell you about the "reality" behind the data), then just:

```
k <- a[ !is.na(a$fac1_num) , ]
```

That way you will still have the original character value in the `a` data-object and can examine its values if needed. The proper test for "numericy" is `is.numeric`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **sapply** with **mode** :

```
sapply(your_df, mode)
```